Are the complex numbers a graded algebra?
I'm working with these definitions:
Algebra
An algebra, $A$, over a field $\mathbb{K}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$ equipped with a bilinear product:
$$\mu: A \times A \to A.$$
Graded Algebra
An algebra, $A$, is said to be $\textit{graded}$ if:
$$
A=\bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}A_i,
$$
and for $a_i \in A_i$ and $a_j \in A_j$ we have that $\mu(a_i,a_j) \in A_{i+j}$.
Note: in fact, this notion of a grading can be made more general only imposing that:
$$
A=\bigoplus_{g\in G}A_g,
$$
for a semi-group $G$. But we usually only require the special case of $G = \mathbb{Z}$.

I then decided to examine this table from wikipedia:

to figure out which algebras were graded. It looks to me like only polynomials are graded (possibly quaternions, but I don't even know what they are, so let's not worry about that actually). Regardless, my intuition says that the complex numbers aren't graded (they aren't ordered, though I think this is independent).
Then I realized that I could indeed asign to every complex number a "weight" given by the modulus. And indeed, the weight of the product of two complex numbers is the product of the weights of the two complex numbers: $|zw| = |z||w|$. I don't believe it is possible however to write: $$\mathbb{C} = \bigoplus_{r\in \mathbb{R^+} \cup \{0 \}} C_r$$ where $C_r$ denotes the complex numbers of modulus $r$. I'm just pretty uncertain.
Additional note: it seems easy (at least simple) to me to prove an algebra is graded, it seems near impossible to prove an algebra is not graded (i.e. how can I guarantee that matrix multiplication isn't graded)?

Every algebra $A$ can be made into a graded algebra trivially: Just let $A_0 = A$ and $A_i = 0$ for all $i \neq 0$.
With this out of the way, let's see whether we can make $\mathbb{C}$ into a graded $\mathbb{R}$-algebra in any non-trivial way. Note that since $\mathbb{C}$ has dimension 2 over $\mathbb{R}$, there are at most two $A_i$ in the decomposition that can be nonzero. But we know that if $A_i \neq 0$ for some $i \neq 0$, then $\mu(x, x) \in A_{2i}$ for all $x \in A_i \setminus \{0\}$, and since $\mu(x, x) \neq 0$ we then find that $\mu(\mu(x, x), \mu(x, x)) \in A_{4i}$ is non-trivial, so iterating this procedure we find that $A_{2^n i}$ is non-trivial for all $n$, contradicting the dimensionality of $\mathbb{C}$.
In particular your approach for filtering by modulus doesn't work: The $C_r$ aren't vector spaces, since multiplying with a constant $r \in \mathbb{R}$ changes the modulus.

The $C_r$ are circles; express them as $r e^{i\pi \theta}$ and scale $\theta$?  I guess the problem is that the 0s don't agree.

@Yakk It's an easy exercise in elementary linear algebra to show that that operation does not give a vector space structure on $C_r$ (hint: in a vector space multiplication with a non-zero scalar is a bijection).

@Yakk That's not a field.

Look a bit closer at your definition of graded algebra, and in particular the definition of the $A_i$. Yes, they must interact in the way you describe, but there is a requirement that's asked of each one in isolation: they are abelian groups under the algebra addition (and actually $A_0$-modules, assuming your index set is at least a monoid). And this is not true for the decomposition you propose.
On the other hand, the standard decomposition of the complex numbers into a real and an imaginary part does give you a $\Bbb Z_2$-grading over $\Bbb R$.


it seems near impossible to prove an algebra is not graded (i.e. how can I guarantee that matrix multiplication isn't graded)?

Here is a general discussion. If $A = \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} A_i$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded algebra over a field $K$, then the multiplicative group $K^{\times}$ naturally acts on $A$ as follows: if $a \in A_i$ has degree $i$ then a scalar $\lambda \in K^{\times}$ acts by $a \mapsto \lambda^i a$.
Example. If $A = K[x]$ is the polynomial algebra it has a natural grading where $A_i = \text{span}(x^i)$ is $1$-dimensional. Then the above action is just $\lambda : f(x) \mapsto f(\lambda x)$.
So you can rule out the possibility that $A$ has a nontrivial $\mathbb{Z}$-grading (the trivial grading is $A = A_0$) by ruling out the possibility that $A$ admits a nontrivial action of $K^{\times}$. This requires an understanding of the automorphism group $\text{Aut}(A)$ (strictly speaking we need to understand these groups as algebraic groups but we don't need to get into this for now). For example $A = K^n$ has finite automorphism group the symmetric group $S_n$ and this can be used to show that it doesn't admit a nontrivial grading (although in this particular case simpler arguments will work).
However, trying to apply this argument to matrix algebras shows that they can be graded nontrivially. The Skolem-Noether theorem shows that every automorphism of $M_n(K)$ is inner, meaning it is given by conjugation by some invertible matrix. So the automorphism group is the projective general linear group $PGL_n(K)$, and this group does admit interesting nonzero homomorphisms $K^{\times} \to PGL_n(K)$, even very nice polynomial ones, and these are the ones that correspond to nontrivial gradings of $M_n(K)$. For example if $n = 2$ we can consider the action on $A = M_2(K)$ given by conjugation by
$$D(\lambda) = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]$$
where $\lambda \in K^{\times}$. The graded pieces are given by the eigenspaces of this action. The degree zero subspace $A_0$ is the invariant subspace, so it consists of all matrices which commute with $D(\lambda)$, and an easy calculation shows that this is $2$-dimensional with basis $E_{11} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right], E_{22} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]$. More interestingly the degree $i$ subspace $A_i$ is the subspace on which $D(\lambda)$ acts by multiplication by $\lambda^i$. Since $A$ is finite-dimensional, by repeatedly taking powers of $A_i$ you can show that all the nonzero graded pieces must consist of nilpotents, so we can guess that we ought to be looking at the matrices $E_{12} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$ and $E_{21} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right]$, and it's not hard to calculate that
$$D(\lambda) E_{12} D(\lambda)^{-1} = \lambda E_{12}, D(\lambda) E_{21} D(\lambda)^{-1} = \lambda^{-1} E_{21}$$
so altogether $M_2(K)$ admits a nontrivial $\mathbb{Z}$-grading
$$M_2(K) \cong A_{-1} \oplus A_0 \oplus A_1$$
where $A_{-1} = \text{span}(E_{21}), A_0 = \text{span}(E_{11}, E_{22}), A_1 = \text{span}(E_{12})$.
On the other hand, frequently people restrict to the case of $\mathbb{N}$-gradings, and $M_n(K)$ doesn't admit any nontrivial $\mathbb{N}$-gradings. This is because in an $\mathbb{N}$-grading the positive part $\bigoplus_{i > 0} A_i$ must be a two-sided ideal, and $M_n(K)$ is simple.
